# Datetime Offset Conversion in SQL

Tags: sql, offset, datetimeoffset

I’m working with a table that uses date time offset. I have a value that looks like 2020-01-02 13:30:00 -07:00.

Is the time in my time zone 13:30 or do I need to subtract 7 hours from it. I saw people do it differently on YouTube.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product - and there is no data type `datetime` or `date time offset` in standard SQL. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQLServer, the last section of the string representation that you posted of the DateTimeOffset describes the time zone. So, if you are currently located in time zone -7:00 (e.g., Arizona, USA), then the time portion of the string refers to your local time, not UTC. [See the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> For example, 1999-12-12 12:30:30.12345 -07:00 should be represented [in UTC] as
> 1999-12-12 19:30:30.12345Z

Someone would subtract the offset from the number only if they want to manually get the UTC value, but that would might produce errors if the data come from a daylight saving time (DST) region, so you would need to enforce DST handling at the time of entry. SQLServer already stores the data in UTC behind the scenes:

> The data is stored in the database and processed, compared, sorted,
> and indexed in the server as in UTC.